# Sharepoint 2013 "403 - Forbidden: Access is denied." after deploy simple app

Tags: iis, sharepoint-2013

I created a dev site in my Sharepoint farm, then I create a simple "Hello world" app, after the deploy, when I click on my app, I receive the error above.
[image]
Any suggestion? I think something related to IIS...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!
To whom may be useful.
I configured the app domain as a subdomain (following a wiki page on Technet!) instead of a separate domain (as described in Sharepoint 2013 guideline on Technet). 
In details the app subdomain was "app.spsvil.local" I replaced with a new domain "appsvil.local" and now it works!